# CorelDraw using IF function based on text

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I'm trying to create an IF function based off text on the page.

I am working with print merges and populating dozens of merge fields that are hidden and separated into layers with there objects based on which style they go with.

I then manually set `visibility = True` for that style

I know this syntax is wrong, but for the sake of explaining, what I'm trying to do is;

```
If Layer("Style") contains text "MyStyleName"

 Layer("MyStyleName").Visible = True
```

I'm currently using this code with MyStyleLayer1 to MyStyleLayer13 or so

```
If ActivePage.Layers("MyStyleLayer1").Visible = True Then
ActivePage.Layers("MyStyleLayer1").Visible = False
Else: ActivePage.Layers("MyStyleLayer1").Visible = True
End If
```

Each style layer is assigned to a keyboard shortcut and manually shown or hidden

Im trying to automate this process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide layers with name contian 'Layer' you can use this code

```
Sub HideLayer()
' Recorded 20.12.2015
Dim Mylayer As Layer
Dim searchstring As String
searchstring = "Layer"
 For Each Mylayer In ActivePage.Layers
 If InStr(1, Mylayer.Name, searchstring) > 0 Then
  Mylayer.Visible = False
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

To show layer change

```
Mylayer.Visible = False
```

to

```
Mylayer.Visible = true
```

To search string in text on page use this code

```
Public Sub TextFind()
Dim s As Shape
Dim WhatFind as String
Dim CountFind as integer
CountFind = 0
WhatFind = "I"
For Each s In ActiveDocument.ActivePage.Shapes
    If s.Type = cdrTextShape Then
         If InStr(1, s.Text.Story, WhatFind) > 0 Then
         CountFind=CountFind+1
         End If
   End If 
 Next
If CountFind > 0 Then ' do what you want when WhatFind had searched in text
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this program only change layer attribute to hide or show it. What layer show/hide determine by variable 'searchstring' -  variable. 
Search text, deterime what name of layer you whant show/hide, assign  'searchstring' , run program

Comment: Perfect,  your amazing.   Ive looked for this code for almost a month now and you solved it in 24 hours or so... THANK YOU